# Why passing char[] to function instead of char* returns weird chars in the end?

Tags: arrays, c, char, malloc

I have the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void strLower(char *string, char *stringLow);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    char myString[len];
    strLower(argv[1], myString);


    char *myStringP = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    strLower(argv[1], myStringP);

    printf("String[]: %s\nString *: %s\n", myString, myStringP);
}


void strLower(char *string, char *stringLow)
{
    int len = strlen(string);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        stringLow[i] = tolower(string[i]);
    }
}
```

I compiled this doing `gcc test.c -o test` where test.c is the name of my file. After that, I run my program `./test helloworld` and the output was the following:

```sh
./test 
String[]: helloworld#=\U
String *: helloworld
```

I did this multiple times and the last characters on String[] where always different. Why does this happens?

Comment: Looks like you aren't leaving room for the terminating null character in your strings.

Comment: Check this: `char str[] = "hello";` `sizeof(str)` is 6 while `strlen(str)` is 5. Last octet/byte is occupied by c-string delimiter `\0`